# Loading Backbone.Relational using Use! plugin

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, amd, backbone-relational

Backbone Relational is not an AMD compliant library, so I've gone ahead and found the use plugin to ensure underscore and backbone are both loaded as dependencies. Here is my config file

```
require.config({
  baseUrl: '../global/js',
  paths: {
    use: 'libs/utilities/use',
    jquery: 'libs/jquery/jquery-min',
    underscore: 'libs/underscore/underscore-min',
    backbone: 'libs/backbone/backbone-optamd3-min',
    text: 'libs/require/text',
    relational: 'libs/backbone/backbone-relational'
  },
  use:  {
    "relational": {
        deps: ["backbone","underscore"]
    }
  }
 });
```

I've also gone ahead and augmented the Backbone Relational library

```
(function(Backbone, _) {
  "use strict";

  Backbone.Relational = {
        showWarnings: true
  };

})(this.Backbone, this._);
```

Finally, I am calling relational within a model

```
 define([

    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'mediator',
    'relational'

    ], function($, _, Backbone, Mediator){
```

I am getting an error of cannot set property Relational of undefined. Meaning Backbone is not available. What am I missing?

Some links that I have been using
https://github.com/tbranyen/use.js
https://github.com/tbranyen/layoutmanager-example/blob/master/app/index.js
https://raw.github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational/master/backbone-relational.js

Answer (score 0):

Backbone and underscore are not AMD compatible.

[Upgrade warning: versions 1.3.0 and higher remove AMD (RequireJS) support.](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/)

Comment: I am using the AMD branches...still on 1.2.2 of underscore. I should mention the application was working before I added the !use plugin and Backbone Relational

Answer (score 0):

To use (sic) the `use` plugin you do **not** need the AMD versions of underscore/backbone.
You do need to wrap them though accordingly, i.e. in your require config have:

```
    use: {
        backbone: {
            deps: ["use!underscore", "jquery"],
            attach: "Backbone"
        },

        underscore: {
            attach: "_"
        },

        relational: {
            deps: ["use!underscore", "use!backbone"]
        }
        ....
    }
```