# How to make Backbone-Relational (0.8.5) work with RequireJS?

Tags: requirejs, backbone-relational

After another long research, sth comes out :-) It seems the problem is about the function "getObjectByName". It can not work well with requireJS(ADM). Currently, I have to setup a globel var to fix the problem. I am sure there must be have better solution.

Here is my temp soluton:

(1) setup a global var and setup the search model scope to the global ("APP")

```
var APP = {};

define(['backbone-relational'], function(){
    Backbone.Relational.store.addModelScope(APP);
})
```

(2) export your relation model to the global

```
APP.YourRelationalModel = YourRelationModel;
```

It works, not good though... I'm really looking forward to a better answer. Thanks.

//------------

test versions:

```
1.Backbone-Relational 0.8.5 
2.Backbone 1.0.0 and Underscore 1.4.4
3.JQuery 1.8.3
4.RequireJS 2.1.5
```

Code is very simple: (or see https://github.com/bighammer/test_relational_amd.git)

```
require.config({

paths : {

    js                    : 'js',
    jquery                : 'js/jquery-1.8.3',
    underscore            : 'js/underscore',
    backbone              : 'js/backbone',
    'backbone-relational' : 'js/backbone-relational'
},

shim : {
    underscore : {
        exports : '_'
    },
    backbone   : {
        deps    : ['underscore', 'jquery'],
        exports : 'Backbone'
    },

    'backbone-relational' : {
        deps: ['backbone']
    }
}
```

});

```
define(['backbone', 'backbone-relational'], function (Backbone) {

var Child = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend();
var Parent = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
    relations : [
        {
            key          : 'child',
            type         : Backbone.HasOne,
            relatedModel : 'Child'
        }
    ]

});

var test = new Parent();
```

});

save above code in main.js and included in index.html as follows:

It doesn't work. There is warning message:

```
Relation=child: missing model, key or relatedModel (function (){ return parent.apply(this, arguments); }, "child", undefined).
```

I read the source code of backbone-relational and know there is something wrong with the namespace. Relational-Backbone cannot find the relatedModel defined in "Parent" (i.e. cannot find releatedMode:"Child"). I failed to find the solution to fix this due to my limited knowledge of javascript :-)

Can anyone help me with this?

Before I asked my question, I studied the following solutions:

[Backbone.RelationalModel using requireJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11224858/backbone-relationalmodel-using-requirejs)
[Can't get Backbone-relational to work with AMD (RequireJS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11955309/cant-get-backbone-relational-to-work-with-amd-requirejs?rq=1)
[Loading Backbone.Relational using Use! plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659454/loading-backbone-relational-using-use-plugin?rq=1)

None of them worked in this case.

Comment: After another long research, sth comes out :-) It seems the problem is about the function "getObjectByName". It can not work well with requireJS(ADM). Currently, I have to setup a globel var to fix the problem. I am sure there must be have better solution.

Here is my temp soluton:

(1) setup a global var and setup the search model scope to the global ("APP")
var APP = {};

define(['backbone-relational'], function(){
    Backbone.Relational.store.addModelScope(APP);
})
(2)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't have to reference relatedModel by string, you can reference it directly, so instead of `relatedModel: 'Child'`, just use: `relatedModel: Child`.

And since you are using requireJS, you can reference model from other file easily.

```
define(['backbone', 'models/child', 'backbone-relational'], function (Backbone, Child) {
  var Parent = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
    relations : [{
        key          : 'child',
        type         : Backbone.HasOne,
        relatedModel : Child
    }]
  });

  var test = new Parent();
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. Actually, I tried to use Reference one time, but i did not work. Now figure out why it did not work that time. It is caused by my other mistake in the project source code :(

Answer (score 0):

The above solution didn't apply to me. I am gradually moving code out of Rails Asset Pipeline (not RequireJS/AMD/CommonJS/anything) into Webpack, starting with dependencies. When I moved requiring `backbone-relational` into Webpack bundle preparation by my models and relation definitions were still in Rails Asset Pipeline, I started getting a lot of unexplained `Relation=child: missing model, key or relatedModel (function (){ return parent.apply(this, arguments); }, "child", undefined).`

In *my* case, the solution ended up being quite simple, despite taking a long time to discover on my part:

```
// In a Webpack module, later included into Rails Asset Pipeline
// temporarily to facilitate migration

require('expose?Backbone!backbone') // Exposing just for migration
require('backbone-relational')
Backbone.Relational.store.addModelScope(window)
```

`backbone-relational` by default uses its global scope to resolve string-based `relatedModel`s but since it was required without a *real* global scope, the solution is simply to pass that in using `addModelScope` so it can search that scope for the specified models.